# Get SQL description as model description when scaffolding

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I would like to get the extended sql-property "MS_Description" as seen in the SQL Management Studio to represent the summary of properties in the models.

When I'm doing a scaffold of the database, for example

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=xxx.xx.xx.xx;Database=DBName;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=somethingSecret" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models --project ProjectName --force
```

the scaffolded model should look something like this:

```
public partial class TestClass
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Primary key or whatever i have wrote in the description
        /// </summary>
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Description2
        /// </summary>
        public long? Parameter2 { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Description3
        /// </summary>
        public double? Parameter3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Not sure about what you need. Is `Description` a column in your table? or you'd like to have `Description` to be calculated based on the other fields in the table?

Comment: @trailmax "description" here is the `MS_Description` extended property metadata field, a feature in SQL Server that can be applied to any DB entity (table, column, database, etc)

Comment: @MarcGravell ah, that one. So rarely used, I've totally forgotten about it.

Comment: Exactly -  it's the MS_Description i'm looking for. We have a very DB-first approach here. :)

Comment: This is a good idea, and should probably be a feature request over on GitHub: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore